# Renaming all files within multiple subfolder structures to parent folder using VBA

Tags: excel, rename, subdirectory, directory-structure

I have a main folder, with many subfolders, and now I have subfolders within this top layer of subfolders, with files then within those multiple layers of subfolders. I would like to add the suffix of the top layer subfolder to the prefix of every file within all additional layers of subfolders. I would then like to export all files within all subfolders, with the new prefix, to a new general folder to be bulk uploaded into a platform.

Before: C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\ is main folder, within this main folder there are many subfolders C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345, within these subfolders, there are now additional subfolders (and sometimes additional folders within those folders),
C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345\Contracts
C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345\ImportantDocuments\NDA, then within these additional subfolders are the target files:
C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345\Contracts\employeecontract.pdf
C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345\ImportantDocuments\NDA\confidentialityagreement.pdf ...

After: C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345
C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345\Contracts\12345_employeecontract.pdf C:\DESKTOP\EMPLOYEES\JOHN_DOE_12345\ImportantDocuments\NDA\12345_confidentialityagreement.pdf

The number of layers of subfolders within subfolders might vary, but ideally I just want to get all the way down to the file level and apply the suffix of that original subfolder (so the JOHN_DOE_12345 in this case) to any file within (no matter what additional subfolder it is in).

I have VBA below (thanks @VBasic2008) that has been working great to at least rename the files with the folder name and then copy all files to a new destination folder for import, but now I need to alter it a little to search through multiple layers of subfolders.

I need to do this in bulk based on the EMPLOYEES parent folder in this case - so it's not an option to continue changing the original folder path to one layer up or down.

Any help would be appreciated!

- This will not modify the source files.
- It will copy them renamed to the destination folder.
- Make sure that the code works correctly before you replace .Copy with .Move to move them.
- Adjust the worksheet name Sheet1 and the cell holding the destination path A8.

```
Sub CopyFiles()
    ' Add reference: Tools->References->Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' ADJUST!
    
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
   
    ' Get the source folder (object).
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = CStr(ws.Range("A7").Value)
    If Not fso.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The source folder """ & sFolderPath & """ doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim sFolder As Folder: Set sFolder = fso.GetFolder(sFolderPath)
    
    ' Get the destination folder path (string).
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = CStr(ws.Range("A8").Value) ' ADJUST!
    If Not fso.FolderExists(dFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The destination folder """ & dFolderPath & """ doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sSubfolder As Folder
    Dim sFile As File
    Dim sDelimiterPosition As Long
    Dim ssName As String
    Dim dPrefix As String
    Dim dPath As String
    
    ' Do it.
    For Each sSubfolder In sFolder.SubFolders
        ssName = sSubfolder.Name
        sDelimiterPosition = InStrRev(ssName, "_")
        If sDelimiterPosition > 0 Then ' subfolder has delimiter
            dPrefix = Right(ssName, Len(ssName) - sDelimiterPosition)
            For Each sFile In sSubfolder.Files
                dPath = fso.BuildPath(dFolderPath, dPrefix & "_" & sFile.Name)
                sFile.Copy Destination:=dPath ', OverWriteFiles:=True ' default
            Next sFile
        'Else ' subfolder doesn't have delimiter; do nothing
        End If
    Next sSubfolder

End Sub
```

I tried this code for multiple layers of subfolders, but it produced nothing.

Comment: Install yourself a copy of RegexRenamer and also 7-ZIP and make it easy on yourself.  RegexRenamer can utilize capture groups to help you put a prefix on your files, then 7-ZIP can put them all together in one easy-to-manage file that can be unzipped at its final destination and you get size compression as well!   Using VBA for this purpose is like using a Swiss Army Knife to split firewood.  I have no doubt it can be done, but there are better tools for the purpose.

Comment: I wish it were this easy - the issue we run into is that RegexRenamer and 7-ZIP is not something we can have 100s of non-tech colleagues globally, easily install and understand; we have a colleague in every country and each have their own process. This 'macro' tool was really the last resort to share something they could easily apply and run, with the understanding that yes, it might be bulkier and less efficient.